# How to figure out the used cryptographic algorithm?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, aes

I have two files:

1. one is a raw plain text file which is first compressed using ZStandard and then encoded with Base64
2. one is basically the same file but it is encrypted after the compression but before the encoding. I know the password used und have a 32 byte long salt.

Assumptions made:

- I assume that the algorithm used is aes-128. Why? Because I actually have four files (two pairs) and the biggest common divisor of the two ciphers is 16, so I at least can assume a 128bit blocksize. And AES because it is the most common
- The cipher is not generated using ECB since the same plain text results in different ciphers each time I let it generate.

I can provide one pair with its password and salt. I can also provide multiple pairs all with the same plain text if needed.

What is this for:
I am currently implementing a golang library to communicate with TeamSpeak 3 ServerQuery. It provides the possibility to create snapshots of servers and you can encrypt them using a password. I'd like to decrypt them with the password and the salt to parse and manipulate them.

I was not yet able to figure out, which mode is used with what IV.
I've tried many different possibilities including but not limited to:

- Hashing the password using MD5 and using it as a key
- Hashing the password with the salt using MD5
- Hashing the password and then hashing the password hash and salt using MD5
- Using the first half of the salt in the Key hash and the second half as a iv and vise versa

I am pretty much all out of ideas at this point. If anyone can just so much as point me in a direction would be appreciated.

MfG

Comment: The IV is often prepended to the cyphertext.  Try using the first 16 bytes as the IV for the rest of the file.  And MD5 is broken, you should change to a better hash if you can.

Comment: There is no other option than "try all". But you have to include much more options to, unfortunately: a) The encryption algorithm could be AES, but also e.g. ChaCha20. b) It could be **any** AES mode (including ECB) because c) for using a password a password derivation function like PBKDF2 with a random salt was eventually in use [that explains why you have different ciphertexts with same plaintexts. When a PBKDF2 was in use you need to know (or test) how many iterations the algorithm has run. In the end **my answer / recommendation** is: forget about the idea.

Comment: If a salt is used, it can still be ECB mode, because the salt is used during key derivation and therefore randomizes the key which means the IV can be kept static providing the same security.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I see now I am probably on a endless endeavour. Thanks anyways